# devices not found , is there any changes I have to make?

Tags: flutter

I tried this on android, no Bluetooth devices found I am using **flutter_blue**

```
 FlutterBlue flutterInstance = FlutterBlue.instance;

  void _scanBT() {
    print('triggered');
    // this line will start scanning bluetooth devices
    flutterInstance.startScan(timeout: Duration(seconds: 4));
    var scanDevices = flutterInstance.scanResults.listen((scanResult) {
      print(scanResult);
    }); // this line will stop scanning bluetooth devices
    scanDevices.cancel();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem is very common when your devices have turn off her GPS.

If you active the GPS in both devices then you will find your devices.

PD: Make sure that your devices are visibles to other devices (In bluetooth settings)

Comment: not working already I have tried

Comment: this appeared in console D/BluetoothAdapter( 9110): isLeEnabled(): ON
E/CheckPermission( 9110): _bluetooth code = 10
D/BluetoothLeScanner( 9110): onScannerRegistered() - status=0 scannerId=8 mScannerId=0
D/BluetoothAdapter( 9110): isLeEnabled(): ON

Comment: comment this line scanDevices.cancel(); and change 4 seconds of the duration to 60 seconds.

Comment: And try add scanMode to lowLatency to improve the signal.

Comment: not working  D/BluetoothAdapter( 9110): isLeEnabled(): ON
2
I/flutter ( 9110): []

Comment: The permissions of GPS is in always permission?

Comment: yes always allowed

Comment: That is really strange, you are use physical device, right?

Comment: yes I am using physical device